# DCC plot showing 2 plots instead of 4

Tags: r

I am running a DCC model and I want to obtain various plots. I however get just get 2 plots I tried to use par(mfrow=c(2,2)) but I still get 2 plots in stead of 4.
Here is my code below. Any help will be appreciated.

```
 head(rtn)
     Chemicals   General Consumergoods  AllShare
[1,] -0.019739 -0.381280     -0.035180 -0.064606
[2,] -0.073141 -0.023573      0.103019  0.004151
[3,] -0.057789 -0.149117      0.008271 -0.068652
[4,] -0.020769  0.040694      0.029159 -0.010299
[5,]  0.046813 -0.262773      0.057656  0.053516
[6,] -0.024097  0.218879      0.033004  0.006752

spec = ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0,0)), variance.model = list(garchOrder = c(1,1), 
                         model = "sGARCH"), distribution.model = "norm")

dccspec = dccspec(uspec = multispec( replicate(4,spec) ),dccOrder = c(1,1), distribution = "mvnorm")
dccspec

dcc.fit = dccfit(dccspec, data = rtn)
plot(dcc.fit, which=2)
```

[image: plots obtained]

Comment: what happens when you remove the `which=2` from the plot call? Also, please add the `library` calls to your code so we know what packages you are using.

Comment: Thank you, I am using the rmgarch package i.e library(rmagarch).  If I remove which=2 the same happens.  It gives me option to select plots after which it gives me 2 plots instead of 4.    This is what happens:                                                                                           
Make a plot selection (or 0 to exit): 

1:   Conditional Mean (vs Realized Returns)
2:   Conditional Sigma (vs Realized Absolute Returns)
3:   Conditional Covariance
4:   Conditional Correlation
5:   EW Portfolio Plot with conditional density VaR limits